# Camera Overlay View - UIButton Not Working

Tags: ios, uiview, camera, uibutton, camera-overlay

I've created an overlay view for a camera with two buttons, a take picture button and a switch camera button. Take picture should take the picture and switch camera should change the rear view and front view camera. Neither of the things work. I've made an app like this a few months ago, and everything worked fine. I have the same code, and I don't know why the buttons don't work anymore. Any input is appreciated! If code is necessary I'll be happy to put it up!

Here's some code:

These are the connected buttons:

```
-(IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Taken");
    [self.picker takePicture]; //Picker is the UIImagePickerController
}

-(IBAction)switchCamera:(id)sender{
    if (self.picker.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear) {
         self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    } else{
       self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    }
}
```

I've connected the custom .xib view as to `@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *overlay`

Comment: put some code and also first give backGround color of your overlay view for checking that surly your overlay view covered/added button or not...

Comment: I added some code, if you need anything other code let me know, and the buttons do show up, they just don't work when you tap on them

Comment: i am telling you because i have same issue (overlap) with QRScan.. so check with **backGround color of your overlay view**

Comment: and change @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *overlay;

Comment: I added the strong to the UIView property, and the background color set for the overlay in the .xib file is the White Color

Comment: change color red and check your button displayed under red color or not ??

Comment: It doesn't, it displays under a black color!

Comment: SO..that way// your you can not able to touch button because your button not on your overlap view...

Comment: ahhh I see, but do you know why that is?? and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39543/discussion-between-ipatel-and-aj-s)